# Javascript scope with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, object

I am trying to use ajax while entering data to ajax by passing it to a object.
However it can't normally use the object data.

Here is the object I created for ajax data in JSON

```
$specialType="";
obj={};
obj.size = $("#size").val();
obj.type = $("#type").val();
obj.length = $("#length").val();
obj.zipperend = $("#zipperend").val();
obj.specialType = $specialType;
```

Below is the function I used to change the $specialType whenever body is clicked

```
$("body").click(
    function(){
        if ($type.val()=="foo" || $type.val()=="bar"){
            $specialType = $A.val();
        }else if($type.val()=="nylon"){
            $specialType = $B.val();
        }else{
            $specialType = $C.val();
        }
    }//end annoymous function
)//end click
```

I have used console log to check the value of $special type everytime I clicked the body, it show correctly, but the problem is whenever I console log the obj, it always say $specialType is not defined. I really wonder how could I solve this scoping problem. Thank you very much for anyone willing to answer this question.

Comment: Assigning to `$specialType` doesn't change `obj.specialType`. They're two separate variables.

Comment: When the first block of code runs, it will set `obj.specialType` to the _value_ of `$specialType` at that time.  It doesn't link the property to the variable.  When the value of `$specialType` changes during the `click` handler, it won't automatically update your object as well, it has no reference to it.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thank you very much to two very generous gentleman. May I ask if I am doing the right thing to solve this problem. Currently I solved this problem by throwing the function away and directly cut the code which is inside the function, to the global scope. It turns out it works great and everything seems solved. But I am wondering if there are better solution.